# Calculating Requests Per Minute From Timetstamps in RDD during mapping

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

I am currently trying to enrich data for machine learning with requests per minute. The data is stored in a Kafka topic and on application start the whole content of the topic is loaded and processed - therefore it is not possible to use any window operations of spark streaming to my knowledge, as all data will arrive at the same time.

My approach was to try the following:

```
val kMeansFeatureRdd = kMeansInformationRdd.map(x => {

  val begin = x._2 //Long - unix timestamp millis
  val duration = x._3 //Long
  val rpm = kMeansInformationRdd.filter(y => (x._2 - 60000 <= y._2 && x._2 >= y._2)).count()

  (duration, rpm)

})
```

However on this approach I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext. It could happen in the following cases: 
(1) RDD transformations and actions are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
(2) When a Spark Streaming job recovers from checkpoint, this exception will be hit if a reference to an RDD not defined by the streaming job is used in DStream operations. For more information, See SPARK-13758.
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do?

If you need any more information just drop me a comment and I will update what you need.

EDIT:

Broadcasting an RDD does not work. Broadcasting the collected Array does not result in an acceptable performance.

What will be executed but is horribly slow and therefore not really an option:

```
  val collected = kMeansInformationRdd.collect()


    val kMeansFeatureRdd = kMeansInformationRdd.map(x => {
      val begin = x._2 //Long - unix timestamp millis
      val duration = x._3 //Long

      val rpm = collected.filter(y => (x._2 - 60000 <= y._2 && x._2 >= y._2)).size

      (duration, rpm)

    })
```

UPDATE:

This code is at least able to get the job done way faster - but as far as I see it still gets slower the higher the requests per minute are as the filtered array grows - interesting enough it gets slower towards the end what I cannot figure out why. If someone sees the issue - or performance issues that could be generally improved - I would be happy if you let me know.

```
kMeansInformationRdd = kMeansInformationRdd.cache()

    kMeansInformationRdd.sortBy(_._2, true)

    var kMeansFeatureArray: Array[(String, Long, Long)] = Array()
    var buffer: collection.mutable.Map[String, Array[Long]] = collection.mutable.Map()
    var counter = 0


    kMeansInformationRdd.collect.foreach(x => {
      val ts = x._2
      val identifier = x._1 //make sure the identifier represents actually the entity that receives the traffic -e.g. machine (IP?) not only endpoint

      var bufferInstance = buffer.get(identifier).getOrElse(Array[Long]())

      bufferInstance = bufferInstance ++ Array(ts)

      bufferInstance = bufferInstance.filter(p => p > ts-1000)          

      buffer.put(identifier, bufferInstance)

      val rpm = bufferInstance.size.toLong

      kMeansFeatureArray = kMeansFeatureArray ++ Array((identifier, x._3, rpm)) //identifier, duration, rpm
      counter = counter +1
      if(counter % 10000==0){
        println(counter)
        println((identifier, x._3, rpm))
        println((instanceSizeBefore, instanceSizeAfter))
      }

    })

    val kMeansFeatureRdd = sc.parallelize(kMeansFeatureArray)
```

Comment: What's exactly the intention? For each element, find all elements that are within a minute of the start and count them? Is it important that the time ranges are based on the specific start of each event? or could we create windows over the continuum of events and count there?

Answer (score 0):

The code that is given in the EDIT section is not correct. It is not the correct way a variable is broadcasted in Spark. The correct way is as follows:

```
val collected = sc.broadcast(kMeansInformationRdd.collect())


    val kMeansFeatureRdd = kMeansInformationRdd.map(x => {
      val begin = x._2 //Long - unix timestamp millis
      val duration = x._3 //Long

      val rpm = collected.value.filter(y => (x._2 - 60000 <= y._2 && x._2 >= y._2)).size

      (duration, rpm)

    })
```

Of course, you can use global variables as well instead of `sc.broadcast`, but that is not recommended. Why?

The reason is that the difference between using an external variable DIRECTLY(as my so called "global variable"), and BROADCASTING a variable using sc.broadcast() is:

1. When using the external variable directly, spark will send a copy of the serialized variable together with each TASK. Whereas by `sc.broadcast`, the variable is sent one copy per EXECUTOR. The number of Task is normally 10 times larger than the Executor. So when the variable (say an array) is large enough (more than 10-20K), the former operation may cost a lot time on network transformation and cause frequent GC, which slows the spark down. Hence large variable(>10-20K) is suggested to be broadcasted explicitly.
2. When using the external variable directly the variable is not persisted, it ends with the task and thus can not be reused. Whereas by `sc.broadcast()` the variable is auto-persisted in the executors' memory, it lasts until you explicitly unpersist it. Thus sc.broadcast variable is available across tasks and stages.

So if the variable is expected to be used multiple times, `sc.broadcast()` is suggested.

Comment: I tried broadcasting of the collected Array - but that seemed do give no performance improvements. The job runs forever and does not terminate. And I am currently only running a relatively small test set.

Comment: 150k at the moment. I am just working on improving the algorithm approach. I guess filter() on the whole data set is just not the way to go with this amount of data.

Comment: Might be! Have to check it.